# (scala) Can not found registered table spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a test table registered created by

```
case class Test(a:String, b:Integer)
test_df = Array(Test(51550,10), Test(51550,10), Test(51550,10), Test(51550,10), Test(51550,20), Test(51550,20), Test(51550,20), Test(51550,20), Test(51550,16))
sc.parallelize(test_df).toDF().registerTempTable("test")
```

The following query succeeded.

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from test").show()
```

but this one fails

```
%sql

select * from test
```

with error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: test; line 1 pos 14
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:315)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:265)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:300)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkSqlInterpreter.interpret(SparkSqlInterpreter.java:141)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:276)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:118)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: just making sure - are both queries executed using the same Spark SQLContext?

Comment: @TzachZohar I think they are, how can I prove it

Comment: How do you execute this? Some sort of notebook?

Comment: @zero323 I used Zepplin

Comment: OK, could you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It looks like you're messing with contexts but it is hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: If this is in Zeppelin, it should work (although the syntax for creating the test_df above is currently wrong, I assume you have a version that is correct). Are you are running each of the paragraphs in the right order? The paragraph that creates and registers test_df needs to run before the paragraph with the %sql can be run successfully. Are you explicitly creating a SQLContext before executing the Spark syntax above? Zeppelin provides a SQLContext by default that you can reference as sqlContext and is used when you use %sql. If you are creating another one, it will cause the error above.

Comment: @zero323  thanks for the response. What I have published is the MCVE, you can paste that into zepplin and get the error

Comment: @DemetriKots  I haven't explicity create SQLContext, I just used the code I have published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your logs, and if you have something like:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:61)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:300)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:169)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.zeppelin.hive.HiveInterpreter.getConnection(HiveInterpreter.java:184)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.hive.HiveInterpreter.getStatement(HiveInterpreter.java:204)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.hive.HiveInterpreter.executeSql(HiveInterpreter.java:233)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.hive.HiveInterpreter.interpret(HiveInterpreter.java:328)
  at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
```

I had the same issue because Zeppelin by default attempts to load hive context.  To solve it I modified zeppelin to use conf/zeppelin-env.sh

export ZEPPELIN_SPARK_USEHIVECONTEXT=false

Answer (score 1):

in Zeppelin, related to the **different contexts created by spark** mentioned in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671017/1915447

check the following setting in the spark interpreter

```
zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext = false
```

set the setting to 'false'

tested with Zeppelin 0.6.2

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one temporary table in zeppelin you need to use pyspark rather than Scala because Scala using  zeppelin can't create more then one table.